# Merge netCDF files: various unsuccessful attempts

Tags: python, cygwin, netcdf

I'm trying to merge 3 datasets (1981-1990, 1991-2000, 2001-2010) for one variable.
Using Jupyter (Python), as example the features for the period 1981-1990 are:

[image]

Each dataset contains a 10-year period and its size is about 4 GB.

After looking some posts, I tried 4 solutions all of them in Windows 10:

**Jupyter (Python)**

*1. First suggestion*

```
 import xarray as xr
    t2m_81_90 = xr.open_dataset('era5land_2m_temperature_hourly_ene-dic_1981-1990.nc')
    t2m_91_00 = xr.open_dataset('era5land_2m_temperature_hourly_ene-dic_1991-2000.nc')
    t2m_81_00 = xr.merge([t2m_1981_1990,t2m_1991_2000])
```

The result states:

```
C:\Users\eleph\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\alignment.py:307: FutureWarning: Index.__or__ 
operating as a set operation is deprecated, in the future this will be a logical operation matching 
Series.__or__.  Use index.union(other) instead index = joiner(matching_indexes)

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 15.5 GiB for an array with shape (175319, 184, 129) and data type float32
```

*2. Second suggestion*

```
ncrcat era5land_2m_temperature_hourly_ene-dic_1981-1990.nc era5land_2m_temperature_hourly_ene-dic_1991-2000.nc temper_all.nc
```

Result:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

*3. Third suggestion*

```
import netCDF4
from netCDF4 import Dataset

dataset = netCDF4.MFDataset(['era5land_2m_temperature_hourly_ene-dic_1981-1990.nc','era5land_2m_temperature_hourly_ene-dic_1991-2000.nc'])
```

Result:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'netCDF4'
```

I thought the error came because 'netCDF4' was not installed but after trying to install, this showed:

```
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort. failed
```

**CDO (Cygwin)**

*4. Fourth suggestion*

```
$ cdo mergetime era5land_2m_temperature_hourly_ene-dic_1981-1990.nc era5land_2m_temperature_hourly_ene-dic_1991-2000.nc 2m_tempmerature_1981-2000.nc
```

Result:

```
cdf_put_vara_double: name=t2m  type=NC_SHORT  minval=-32767.000000  maxval=33531.000000

Error (cdf_put_vara_double): NetCDF: Numeric conversion not representable
```

I know this post is quite long but I want to show the trials I made. Maybe some of them can be fixed.
Any help to merge these datasets will be appreacited!

Comment: where can we find the data ? Difficult to replicate any of your tentative without them.

Comment: You probably need to change the output precision in CDO. Without the data I cannot provide a solution. But read this thread and play around with the answer given here https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/boards/1/topics/7764

Comment: @matzeri I downloaded via API in Climate Data Store because it let me customize a specific area, but you could give a try with [this](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/reanalysis-era5-land?tab=form)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```py
xarray.open_mfdataset([
    'era5land_2m_temperature_hourly_ene-dic_1981-1990.nc',
    'era5land_2m_temperature_hourly_ene-dic_1991-2000.nc'
])
```

And define parameter `concat_dim` . I guess it should be a time dimension you can concatenate the datasets along.

Tip: Switch parallel mode on when using open multiple files .